# Login in WebView remaind in a browser

Tags: java, android, browser, android-webview

i'm creating a simple webview application that shows a forum page. Of course the forum page ask to login or register but when i click in there and i try to login, the application ask me to continue after the login in a prefered browser.. I don't want do it but i want continue in my application. Is there a way? The forum is hosted in proboards.com if need. The code of application is very simple.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too sure what do you want exactly.
Let me know if this is what you wanted.

When you are working with `webviews` if you want to stay in a `webview` throughout say one particular web site and not let any webpage open in a browser but the `webview` itself then you could do the following:

in your case the website name is

> "http://www.website.com"

So the code should be:

```
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    try {
                      URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                      if( (url.startsWith("http://www.website.com")) ) {
                        //Allow the WebView in your application to do its thing
                        return false;
                      } else {
                        //Pass it to the system, doesn't match your domain
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //Tell the WebView you took care of it.
                        return true;
                      }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false;

                }
            });
            {

            }
```

By doing this any page in that website will open in the webview itself and not the browser. Hope this helps.